# How to count the amount of words said by someone pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this am I'm trying to count the words said by a specific author.

```
Author              Text                   Date
Jake                hey hey my names Jake  1.04.1997
Mac                 hey my names Mac       1.02.2019
Sarah               heymy names Sarah      5.07.2001
```

I've been trying to get it set up in a way where if i were to search for the word "hey" it would produce

```
Author              Count
Jake                2
Mac                 1
```

Comment: I think he meant to put 'Sarah'

Comment: I dont want sarah in there since im only looking for "hey" individually

Comment: Then use the code I answered below and just put white spaces around the word. Like `.count(" hey ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df['Text'].str.count('hey').groupby(df['Author']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  Author  Count
0   Jake      2
1    Mac      0
2  Sarah      1
```

If need filter out rows with 0 values add [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df['Text'].str.count('hey')
df1 = s[ s.gt(0)].groupby(df['Author']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  Author  Count
0   Jake      2
1  Sarah      1
```

EDIT: for test `hey` separately add words boundaries `\b\b` like:

```
df1 = df['Text'].str.count(r'\bhey\b').groupby(df['Author']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  Author  Count
0   Jake      2
1    Mac      1
2  Sarah      0


s = df['Text'].str.count(r'\bhey\b')
df1 = s[ s.gt(0)].groupby(df['Author']).sum().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
  Author  Count
0   Jake      2
1    Mac      1
```

Comment: @Matt - Super, added solution for count `hey` separately with new data in question.

Answer (score 2):

If `df` is your original dataframe

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Author','Count'])
newDF['Author'] = df['Author']
newDF['Count'] = df['Text'].str.count("hey")
newDF.drop(newDF[newDF['Count'] == 0].index, inplace=True)
```